# Generated reference.cs losing code with INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, reference, inotifypropertychanged

I have a service reference which utilises BasicHttpBinding but when the reference.cs is generated using VS, some properties not implementing RaisePropertyChanged now do (although this is acceptable) and logic in the setter is ignored/removed (which is very much not acceptable!).

I've tried configuring the service reference in various different ways and putting the logic in the RaisePropertyChanged event but nothing seems to clear this up.

Any help much appreciated, brief code below.

Original code in service

```
public class Entry : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string m_Firstname;
    private string m_Foo;

    public string Firstname
    {
        get { return m_Firstname; }
        set
        {
            m_Firstname = value;

            Foo = "bar";

            OnPropertyChanged("Firstname");
        }
    }

    public string Foo
    {
        get { return m_Foo; }
        set { m_Foo = value; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null))
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

Generated code in Reference.cs

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.6.1586.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.domain.com/")]
public partial class Entry : object, INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private string firstnameField;
    private string foo;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]
    public string Firstname {
        get { return this.preferredContactMethodField; }
        set {
            this.firstnameField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Firstname");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=2)]
    public string Foo {
        get { return this.foo; }
        set {
            this.foo= value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Foo");
        }
    }


    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the attempt to set Foo in the Firstname setter has gone and the RaisePropertyChanged in Foo setter has appeared.

As far as I can see this is part and parcel of the process which generates the Reference.cs file and there's nothing I can do to get my original code pulling through - especially the attempt to set Foo, is that correct?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the service reference, the client types are auto generated from the service interface. Your specific logic is part of the internal implementation, which the service client knows nothing about.

If you want to have this behavior in the client, you shouldn't manually change the generated code. It will be overwritten whenever you update the reference.

The only solution that works reliably is to isolate the service types in a separate assembly and use this assembly in your service reference. To do that, click on the *Advanced...* button when you create or update the reference and include the assembly in the dialog that opens by adding it to the "use types of these assemblies" list.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned this is a web service (asmx) and standard service reference, not a .svc which is the only way I beleive this would be an option.

Comment: You can also add a service reference with an asmx service.